# Merdeces stalls after 30sec-1min, and battery warning light is on

Tags: engine, electrical, mercedes-benz, stall, 300se

I've got an old but low mileage Mercedes and This problem puzzles me. The car stalls after a short time(30 seconds to 1 minute) after start up and the battery warning light on the dash lights up. I have changed to a new 800cca battery, and did not solve the problem. I then went to change the alternator and serpentine belt and belt tensioner, and problem still exists! It seems the exterior bulb warning light is also on. Since I have changed everything, what else could be the problem?

Comment: Which Mercedes is this? Model and year?

Comment: 1993 300SE 3.2L

Comment: Do you have to jumpstart the battery to get it going again?

Comment: It starts straight away, only to die after another minute or so.

Comment: That sounds like it is nothing to do with the battery or alternator.  The light you are talking about is a charging warning light. It will light when the alternator is not providing power.  Since the engine has stalled, then the alternator is not running and so is not supplying power.  The light will also be on if you turn the ignition on but don't start the engine.